# Cannot install pi-apps

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

So I've recently tried to install pi-apps using:

```
git clone https://github.com/Botspot/pi-apps
```

and it cloned, but when I used:

```
 /home/pi/pi-apps/install
```

it gave me this error:

```
The command 'sudo apt update' failed. Before Pi-Apps will work, you must fix your apt package-management system.
```

And I even tried manually updating using:

```
wget http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/nettle/libnettle6_3.4.1-1_armhf.deb

sudo dpkg -i libnettle6_3.4.1-1_armhf.deb
```

but even that gives me an error:

```
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'libnettle6_3.4.1-1_armhf.deb': No such file or directory
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I tried downloading the package using your wget command. I got `ERROR 404: Not Found`, so I doubt you actually got it either, in which case `dpkg` obviously can't find it. I'd ask the question in [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) -community and delete this one, as cross-posting is frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will give this question to the Raspberry Pi community